# how to output image file from database drupal 7?

Tags: 7, hooks, database, media

I have created testing module that will upload image and outputting it to my page. but, I can't seem to output my image file from my database. here's my code

```
function database_ex_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['database-ex'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Database Form',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access arguments' => array('submit database_ex'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('database_ex_form'),
  );
  return $items;
}

function database_ex_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form['myimage'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add item'),
  );
  return $form;
}


function database_ex_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  $fe_id = db_insert('example')
    ->fields(array(
      'myimage' => $form_state['values']['myimage'],
    ))
    ->execute();

  drupal_set_message(t('Your entry has been added'));
}

//This function supposedly will output my image file inside a div.

function database_ex_submission(){
  //What to do From here!
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To output the image from database you can use [theme_image](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/7)

```
<?php
  $variables = array(
      'path' => 'path/to/img.jpg', 
      'alt' => 'Test alt',
      'title' => 'Test title',
      'width' => '50%',
      'height' => '50%',
      'attributes' => array('class' => 'some-img', 'id' => 'my-img'),
      );
  $img = theme('image', $variables);
?>
```

Comment: I want to retrieve my image file from my database table. thanks

Comment: If you will try to print_r the $form variable you will get the url of your image which is in your database itself so you need to put fetched url of your image 'path' => 'path/to/img.jpg' here in the above code and theme_image will render the image with HTML tag.

Comment: So im getting my file directly from my folder not from my database?

Comment: No, from database only but using theme_image is the standard way to get the image from database, you just need to navigate till your image url from variable $form by using print_r and then append that url after 'path' to render the image.

Comment: how do you output all the images from public:// folder? not just one file

Answer (score 1):

Firstly save image to your server and then you can output the image.

You can save image by using [file_save_upload()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7).

> **file_save_upload** : Saves a file upload to a new location.

```
$file = file_save_upload('myimage',array(), 'public://');
```

Get fileid(fid) of the image

```
$fid=$file->fid;
```

And then save this $fid to your database.

After it get fid from database

```
  $upload_record = file_load($fid);
  $url = $upload_record->uri;

  $render_image = theme(
    'image_style', 
    array(
      'style_name' => 'Style_name', 
      'path' => $url, 
      'getsize' => TRUE, 
      'attributes' => array(
        'width' => '250', 
        'height' => '162')
      )
    );
```

Now print `$render_image` variable where you want to display image.